# Pointer-based binary heap

Tags: c++, design-patterns, iterator, heap, generic-programming

I am going to implement a *pointer-based binary heap*. What i would like, is for the heap to "work" in various ways depending on some parameters. For example, the heap could be represented in many ways: pointers to left child, right child and parent, left child/right sibling style and so on. Independent of representation, i would like the basic implementation to stay the same. For example, i would like not to implement two different *Siftdown* methods, depending on the representation. I was thinking about giving a node type and an iterator type as parameters to the heap. Then, *Siftdown*, say, could use the given iterator to do it's job. Im wondering if it's good style to use iterators in actual implementation code? Also, i am looking into known *design patterns* that might be useful to me. The *Bridge* and *Strategy* patterns seem interesting.

So, my question is twofold:

1. Is it good practice to use iterators in implementation code?
2. Any thoughts on design patterns that would fit my purpose?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I cannot help you too much but is there a reason you do not want to use the Boost d-ary heap?

Comment: Yes. This is for a research project. Actually, i am implementing a priority-queue abtract using a forest of perfect binary heaps, and a novel numeral system (think binomial queues). I have the theoretical part down, but i'm not much of a C++ programmer( C++ is a requirement for various reasons). I know C well though. But, thanks for the reply.

Comment: But i guess the Boost library could serve as a great inspiration. :)

Comment: Give us some code. Maybe remove part 2: "Any thoughts on design patterns that would fit my purpose?" as it is too generic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointer-based binary heap implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720438/pointer-based-binary-heap-implementation)